# how to compare passed object with a object in the function in php

Tags: php, function, object, compare

I need to create a function that takes in one object as its parameter and one must be invoked in the method, compare the two and return the car with the oldest model.

i have this code so far but it doesnt compare the objects, which i it to do.

```
public function oldestCar($car2){

    if(is_a($car2, 'Car')){
    
        return $car2->year;
                    
}
    }
        
}

// instantiating objects
$car1 = new Car('Audi', '2020', 'Black');
$car2 = new Car('Volkswagon', '2016', 'Grey');
```

Comment: So access the year property of the current object via $this, and compare them … where is the actual problem with that?

Comment: im still new with classes and not sure how to do that